# Longest string A a RegExp finds from start, following but not including B

Tags: javascript, regex

I failed formulating the RegExp finding

- the longest and
- not empty sequence from start, that is
- maybe followed by a "<%" or "%>" or a newline, but not includes any of them.

I tried `/^.+?(?=\r?\n|\r|<%|%>)?/`, but it always only matches the first character.

E.g. `e = /^.+?(?=\r?\n|\r|<%|%>)?/.exec("test\nabc")` finds `e[0] = "t"`.

Of cause, grepping for `/\r?\n|\r|<%|%>/` would be possible, but maybe one of you knows a better method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern is pretty close. `^.+?` is lazy, it matches as much as it has to. With `(?=\r?\n|\r|<%|%>)?` being optional, it never has to backtrack - the regex is satisfied after a single character. Removing the `?` will have much better results, but it doesn't take care of a single line of text with no stop words.
A simpler approach is to use the `/m` flag, which makes `$` match the end of the string or the end of the line:

```
/^.*?(?=$|<%|%>)/m
```

I've also changes `+` to `*` - it should take care of empty lines, or lines that begin with `<%` or `%>`.

Working example: http://rubular.com/r/l8Gmhc459i

Comment: Thank you! It works fine for me and I understood your explanation. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this one should do the trick:

```
var re = /^(?:(?![\r\n]|<%|%>).)+/;
```